# Библиотека для постинга в группу VK

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, бот

Подскажите, пожалуйста, библиотеку на Python для управления записями на стене группы (добавить запись на стену\в отложку) vk-api-for-groups просто недоделана, а других библиотек для удобного постинга я не нашёл. Конечно, можно формировать запросы самостоятельно, но, может быть, уже есть способ проще и удобнее?